# Android App crashes only on specific devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-play, google-play-console

I've recently released my first app on Google Play and many users installed it already.
There seem to be no problems so far, except 2 different errors reported by Google Play Console. The errors occurred on multiple versions of the App but only on 2 specific devices, the error always is:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
```

and the details below only show this:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> identifier_replaced <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000014cab88  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk
  #01  pc 00000000014c8de4  /system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk
```

The devices are OnePlus 5T (8.1) and Galaxy S7 edge (8.0).
The app partly uses webviews to show content, so my guess is, the error has to do with this (because of "chrome.apk").

Can someone help me identify the problem, if it's even on my side (maybe it has to do with chrome?) or maybe there is some kind of database by Google, where i can lookup such things?

Comment: There must be some Log in Concole or Tab or in errors

Comment: As for my experience, you likely can do nothing about it, as it is too hard to understand what is causing chrome webview to crash

Comment: How many users are impacted? From what you shared, it seems that Webview from the system image is loaded, which means that the user has never updated Chrome. It could be test devices which didn't install all resources for your app (with the App Bundle, some resources come in a separate APK that Play serves alongside the base APK,  but some bots might be downloading only the base APK)